# Copy a file with a path with spaces in it, in wsl using powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, syntax, copy

### Scenario

I experienced mild difficulties using powershell to command the wsl to copy a file from a path that contains a space. Neither did I find an example for this specific case. Therefore I wondered:

### Question

How can I copy a file that contains a space, or spaces in its path in the wsl, using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The essence was in the following facts:

1. The spaces did not need^ to be escaped with backticks `
2. The path with spaces needs^ to be surrounded with quotation marks " that did need^ to be escaped with backslashes \
3. The entire string needed^ to be surrounded by single quotes '

### Minimal Working Example

An MWE is a powershell script named `exampleCopyCommand.ps1` that copies a file `someFile.txt` into the wsl:

```
[String] $copy = 'sudo cp \"/mnt/c/path with a space in it/subFolder/Taskwarrior-installation/AutoInstallTaskwarrior/src/main/resources/autoinstalltaskwarrior/someFile.txt\" /home/testlinuxname/maintenance/gCal/' #WORKING
Write-Output "CurrentPathCopyCommand="$copy
#wsl $copy # not working
$output = bash -c $copy # working
Write-Host $output
```

### Parameterized Example

An example with variable Strings consisting of paths with spaces in it is:

```
[String] $linuxCurrentPath ="/mnt/c/path with a space in it/subFolder/Taskwarrior-installation/AutoInstallTaskwarrior"
[String] $getLinuxUsername ="testlinuxname"
[String] $getMaintenanceFolderName="maintenance"
[String] $getGCalSyncFolderName="gCal"

[String] $copy = 'sudo cp \"'+$linuxCurrentPath+'/src/main/resources/autoinstalltaskwarrior/askSync.sh\" /home/'+$getLinuxUsername+"/"+$getMaintenanceFolderName+"/"+$getGCalSyncFolderName+"/"


Write-Output "CurrentPathCopyCommand="$copy
#wsl $copy # not working
$output = bash -c $copy # working
Write-Host $output
```

### Notes

^ Need in this context is not an absolute requirement that always has to be satisfied to answer the question, but a requirement that was/has to be satisfied in this particular solution. I can imagine there are other solutions that do not require satisfaction of those needs.